# How do I load and use a .rkt file in command-line Racket's REPL?

Tags: file, include, racket, external, read-eval-print-loop

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 using Racket 7.6. I created this file, hello.rkt:

```
#lang racket

(define (hello) 'hello-world)
(hello)
```

Then I invoked it:

```
> racket hello.rkt
'hello-world
```

Nice. Next I tried to load the code into the REPL and use it:

```
> racket -i hello.rkt
Welcome to Racket v7.6.
> (hello)                          ; the function is unavailable here
; hello: undefined;
;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
;   in module: top-level
; [,bt for context]
> (load "hello.rkt")               ; load gives no error, but ...
> (hello)                          ; the function is unavailable here
; hello: undefined; ...
> (require "hello.rkt")            ; require gives no error ...
'hello-world                       ; and runs (hello), but ...
> (hello)                          ; the function is unavailable here
; hello: undefined; ...
> (include "hello.rkt")            ; include gives no error, but ...
> (hello)                          ; the function is unavailable here
; hello: undefined; ...
> (enter! "hello.rkt")             ; enter! gives no error, but ...
"hello.rkt"> (enter! "other.rkt")  ; if I enter! another file ...
"other.rkt"> (hello)               ; the hello function is unavailable here
; hello: undefined; ...
```

In brief: How do I load files and use their contents in the toplevel command-line REPL context?

Comment: Are you asking about whether you can `enter!` the environment of multiple files at once in the same REPL?

Comment: In MIT Scheme's REPL, when I (load "hello.scm") and (load "other.scm"), the functions in both files are immediately available for use at the toplevel. I'd like to be able to do something like that in Racket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/intro.html, you can "imitate a traditional Lisp environment" by omitting the `#lang` declaration and using `(load <file>)` in the REPL. When I delete the #lang line from the file, I get this interaction:

```
> racket
Welcome to Racket 7.6.
> (load "hello.rkt")
'hello-world
> (hello)
'hello-world
```

The page *does* "strongly recommend against" the practice, favoring module-based code instead.